# Should a function remain async when applying 'no-return-await'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

If using `return await` is unnecessary should the function remain `async`?

> Using return await inside an async function keeps the current function
> in the call stack until the Promise that is being awaited has
> resolved, at the cost of an extra microtask before resolving the outer
> Promise

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await

Example 1

```
async function foo() {
   return await bar();
}
```

Example 2

```
async function foo() {
    return bar();
}
```

Example 3

```
function foo() {
    return bar();
}
```

Bar

```
async function bar() {
    const data = await externalCall();
    const result = anotherFunction(data);
    return result;
}
```

If the first example becomes the second example shouldn't it actually become the third example?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think example 3 is the same as example 2. Async ensures that the function returns a promise, and wraps non-promises in it. See [https://javascript.info/async-await#:~:text=Async%20functions&text=The%20word%20%E2%80%9Casync%E2%80%9D%20before%20a,in%20a%20resolved%20promise%20automatically.&text=So%2C%20async%20ensures%20that%20the,wraps%20non%2Dpromises%20in%20it](https://javascript.info/async-await#:%7E:text=Async%20functions&text=The%20word%20%E2%80%9Casync%E2%80%9D%20before%20a,in%20a%20resolved%20promise%20automatically.&text=So%2C%20async%20ensures%20that%20the,wraps%20non%2Dpromises%20in%20it).

Comment: In that case is there anything to gain by wrapping a promise in another promise? Surely its pointless?

Comment: I think it is pointless unless you return a promise.

Comment: Where is a promise wrapped in another promise?

Comment: I don't know, but I thought that was a small side question from newprogrammer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no point in using async if the function does not return await.

Comment: Not so. AsyncFunctions have the big advantage of always returning Promise, even in the case of a synchronous throw, which will be seen by the caller as an asynchronous throw - ie a rejected Promise.